# Five nights at Freddy's

Tags: apostrophe

What is the meaning of Freddy's?
Why did put apostrophe s at the end of the word Freddy?
What is the grammar rule behind this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possession in Business Name With Apostrophe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260461/possession-in-business-name-with-apostrophe) eg 'The most popular item on the menu at Wendy's is ...'

Comment: It's also used as an abbreviation for someone's home. We say we're going for lunch at Xavier's e.g.

Comment: This is really an ELL question. See duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/178341/41273

Answer (score 1):

This type of construction leaves the final noun unspecified, but refers to some place owned, operated, or somehow associated with the individual. Exactly what type of place is being referred to will be very context dependent. Here's some examples showing similar constructions, with the omitted, implied noun in square brackets:

I'm watching the game at Bill's [house].

I have an appointment at the doctor's [office].

We're getting dinner at Luigi's [restaurant].